# How can I make this conceptual model better?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Good friends. I'm working on a Laravel application which is like a Student Management System for Schools in my Country. The application requires that I stored scores of students and further generate reports for the period or semester the student achieved that score.

In my Country normally there are six(6) periods in an academic year. A period spans 4 weeks. Also there are two(2) semesters in an academic year which spans 3 and a half months. There are four(4) terms in every semester.

Here is a picture that explains how things looks:

[image]

Since I have to generate a report of each student for a given period of semester this is how my conceptual model looks:

Students table:

```
students
--------
id *
name
grade_id (fk)
```

Subjects table:

```
subjects
--------
id *
name
```

Grades table:

```
grades
--------
id *
name
```

**Note** The grades table store the name of each class in the school. ex. `grade 12`, `grade 11` etc.

Now, these are the tables the student scores for subjects of a given period or semester are store in.

```
period_one (1st Period)
-----------------------
id *
student_id (fk)
subject_id (fk)
grade_id (fk)
score

first_exam (1st Sem. Exam)
-----------------------
id *
student_id (fk)
subject_id (fk)
grade_id (fk)
score

period_four (4th Period)
-----------------------
id *
student_id (fk)
subject_id (fk)
grade_id (fk)
score
```

**Note** the same holds true for `second period`, `third period`, `5th period`, `six period` etc

By this time I know someone have seen something fishy or unintelligent here. I'm repeating the same columns in every table and I believe that it could be done better.

But there is a reason why I did it this way and that has to do with generating reports. With the above setup I can easily structure my queries to generate reports.

This is the query I used to generate periodic reports

```
// the function runs a select all query for all the period/term grades tables
// It displays the periodic grades sheet

$student_id = 1; // any id could be passed
$term = "period_one"; // giving the exact table name to fetch record from
$class_id = 2; // 2 may represent grade 12 in this case.

function periodic_report($term, $student_id, $class_id)
{
    global $connection;
    $query = "SELECT $table.student_id, score, subject_name, class_name
                from $term
                INNER JOIN students
                        ON students.student_id = $table.student_id
                    INNER JOIN classes
                        ON classes.class_id = $table.class_id
                    INNER JOIN subjects
                        ON subjects.subject_id = $table.subject_id
              WHERE $table.student_id = $student_id AND $table.class_id = $class_id";

    $result_set = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

    // Test if there was a query/syntax error
    confirm_query($result_set);
    return $result_set;
}
```

this is how the result may look:

[image]

Query to generate first semester reports:

```
// the function runs a select all query for semester grades
// It displays the first semester grades sheet
function first_semester_report($student_id) {
    global $connection;
    $query = "SELECT subjects.subject_name, period_one.score, period_two.score, period_three.score, first_exam.score
        FROM subjects

        LEFT JOIN period_one 
            ON period_one.subject_id = subjects.subject_id 
            AND period_one.student_id = {$student_id}

        LEFT JOIN period_two 
            ON period_two.subject_id = subjects.subject_id 
            AND period_two.student_id = {$student_id}

        LEFT JOIN period_three
            ON period_three.subject_id = subjects.subject_id 
            AND period_three.student_id = {$student_id}

        LEFT JOIN first_exam
            ON first_exam.subject_id = subjects.subject_id 
            AND first_exam.student_id = {$student_id}

        LEFT JOIN students
            ON students.student_id = {$student_id}

        WHERE period_one.subject_id = subjects.subject_id OR period_two.subject_id = subjects.subject_id OR period_three.subject_id = subjects.subject_id OR first_exam.subject_id = subjects.subject_id
        ORDER BY subjects.subject_name";      

    $result_set = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

    if(!$result_set){
        die("Database query failed. Error from first semester report: ".mysqli_error($connection)." Error number is: ".mysqli_errno($connection));
    }


    // Test if there was a query/syntax error
    //confirm_query($result_set);
    return $result_set;
}
```

Query to generate second semester report:

```
// the function runs a select all query for semester grades
// It displays the second semester grades sheet
function second_semester_report($student_id) {
    global $connection;
    $query = "SELECT subjects.subject_name, period_four.score, period_five.score, period_six.score, second_exam.score
        FROM subjects

        LEFT JOIN period_four 
            ON period_four.subject_id = subjects.subject_id 
            AND period_four.student_id = {$student_id}

        LEFT JOIN period_five 
            ON period_five.subject_id = subjects.subject_id 
            AND period_five.student_id = {$student_id}

        LEFT JOIN period_six
            ON period_six.subject_id = subjects.subject_id 
            AND period_six.student_id = {$student_id}

        LEFT JOIN second_exam
            ON second_exam.subject_id = subjects.subject_id 
            AND second_exam.student_id = {$student_id}

        LEFT JOIN students
            ON students.student_id = {$student_id}

        WHERE period_four.subject_id = subjects.subject_id OR period_five.subject_id = subjects.subject_id OR period_six.subject_id = subjects.subject_id OR second_exam.subject_id = subjects.subject_id
        ORDER BY subjects.subject_name";      

    $result_set = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

    if(!$result_set){
        die("Database query failed. Error from second semester report: ".mysqli_error($connection)." Error number is: ".mysqli_errno($connection));
    }


    // Test if there was a query/syntax error
    //confirm_query($result_set);
    return $result_set;
}
```

this is how the semester report may look based on the semester query for:
[image]

At times I'm trouble that this could be done better, but the shame is I don't know how.

Are there better ways to do this? Also it's only 70 percent of schools who plan their academic year in periods others use different ways. Is there a way to customize this in a way that schools can specified the periods or terms in the academic year and a table be created for each period or term?

Will appreciate practical implications and suggestions. Thanks!!!!

Comment: "By this time I know someone have seen something fishy" You are completely right here. Those should be just one table `period` with an Id, or "enum" to identify the period. Also your first_exam table, I guess that you have also a second_exam and so forth, The same apply here. They should be just one table. As for your statement: "With the above setup I can easily structure my queries to generate reports." You can do even easier with a well normalized structure.

Comment: @JorgeCampos can you please practically show me how to do it.

Comment: well he's just suggested two practical steps you can take. First though, study the topic of database modelling, entity-relations and normalisation in general, and then you will understand better how to structure any database that you create. Even before that, one simply principle you can apply here: If you find yourself repeating the same column names in multiple tables, chances are those tables can be merged, maybe with one extra column as an attribute to distinguish what exact kind of row it is. This would apply to your period tables here, for example.

Comment: the students and subjects tables look like they are ok, you got all the students in one table, all the subjects in one table. So consider that periods are all one kind of thing (just varying by date perhaps), therefore all in one table, and exams are all one kind of thing (just varying by subject, perhaps) and therefore belong all in one table.

Comment: @ADyson I know I can easily create a table like this: `grades(id , studentId, subjectId, periodOne, periodTwo, periodThree, periodOfour, etc`) but my main concern is with generating reports. How do I adopt the queries I now have to the new way you guys are suggesting?

Comment: [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)! Currently this is a massive wall of text, please edit your question to be Minimal, complete and verifiable. This will help others solve your problem and will improve the odds of your question actually helping somebody else along the way!

Comment: I wouldn't create a grades table like that. That isn't normalised either. . Each row should contain a single periodID. A properly normalised structure would be `grades(id, studentID, subjectId, periodId, gradeValue)`. Then when you write a query about the grades you link it to each of the other tables (students, subjects, periods) using INNER JOINs or LEFT JOINs in your SQL as appropriate. You'll get one row for each grade given. If you want to rearrange that into one row per student, you can do it via your application logic, or possibly using a pivot query if your DBMS supports that

Comment: with this you're suggesting that I also create another table to stored all the periods right?

Comment: yes, Jorge Campos suggested it in the first comment - create one table for all periods, instead of separate tables for each period. They are all the same type of thing, so they belong together in one table. You have one _row_ in the table for each period, and you can use columns with suitable values to distinguish between them in whatever way you need (by time, or ID, or name, or whatever). Then you can use the period ID in your grades table.

Comment: @ADyson I followed as you suggested but now I'm having problems arranging or formatting the data return. Please take a look at this thread I created: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45170192/how-to-rearrange-results-returned-by-inner-join-query