# How to rearrange results returned by inner join query

Tags: mysql, join

I have five tables students, classes, subjects, scores, and scores.I'm performing an inner join on these tables to return results. This how my schema looks:

Students table:

```
students
--------
id *
name
class_id (fk)
```

Subjects table:

```
subjects
--------
id *
name
```

Class table:

```
classes
--------
id *
name
```

Term table:

```
terms
--------
id *
name
```

Scores Table:

```
scores
---------------
id *
student_id (fk)
subject_id (fk)
class_id (fk)
term_id (fk)
score
```

Now this is the query I wrote to return results:

```
SELECT students.name as Name, subjects.name as Subject, classes.name as Class, terms.name as Term, scores as Score

// id 1 for student Nathan
// term 1 for first Period
// term 2 for second period
// term 3 for third period

from scores
    inner join students
        on students.id = scores.student_id
        and scores.student_id = 1
    inner join subjects
        on subjects.id = scores.subject_id
        and scores.student_id = 1
    inner join classes
        on classes.id = scores.class_id
        and scores.student_id = 1
    inner join terms 
        on terms.id = scores.term_id
        and scores.student_id = 1

where scores.term_id = 1 or scores.term_id = 2 or scores.term_id = 3
ORDER BY scores.term_id;
```

This is the result return by the query:

[image]

This without doubt is returning the correct result, but the little problem I have is that it is not formatted or structure in the way I need it to be.
This is a bit of light on how I want it to be structure:

[image]

PerioOne, PeriodTwo, and PeriodThree corresponds to the term ids in the scores table with their scores respectively. The picture above shows the final results of how it's going to be display in a html table.

This is how I want the results to be return in mysql:

```
Name | subject | class | first Period | Second Period | Third Period
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Nathan | 1      | 1     |  96          | 71            | 74 
Nathan | 2      | 1     |  96          | 71            | 74
```

Is there a way I can restructure my query to get this done? For clarity sake here is the data in my scores table:

[image]

Comment: it's something you can do in your application layer much more easily. MySQL doesn't really have this kind of functionality, although you _could_ do it in a clunky way if you know the number of periods will always be the same forever.

Comment: @ADyson if you say application layer, do you mean html? if so can you show an example of how you're going to structure the html table?

Comment: well really I mean whatever server-side language you are using to create the HTML (e.g. C#, PHP etc) - you would get your query results and use your server code to process the results in such a way as to display the output in the format you need. The HTML would be structured so it produces the table as per your example of desired output.

Comment: @ADyson I really don't understand. I have updated my post to show how really I want the results returned. Now, the update I did corresponds to the very first way my schema was structure as stated here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45143893/how-can-i-make-this-conceptual-model-better I want to be able to get the same results based on the way I've updated my schema. I thought there's a way to structure the query so that I get the results that I want.

Comment: @ADyson as per the server side language I'm using laravel which is a PhP framework

Comment: no there isn't a direct way to make the query like that. Other DBMS such as SQL Server have some additional functionality like PIVOT queries which would help. MySQL unfortunately doesn't. So you can use your application code instead to compose the results into a specific view.  But the schema is more flexible. The way you had it before would only really allow that one particular query to be run efficiently, whereas your properly normalised schema (well done BTW) will allow other queries more easily, which you will see if you continue to build your application for other uses.

Comment: You have a database.  It must be used by some application. Do whatever you want to do on the application side.

Comment: @Eric I don't fully understand your point. The thing is I don't how I'm going to do it on the application side.

Comment: firstly you should add all the unique IDs to your query output e.g. studentID, subjectID etc. They will be useful. Order your query by studentID, then subjectID, then classID, then termID. On the application side, loop through your resulting rows one by one. Use variables initialised outside the loop to keep track of the current student, current class, current period. Build a HTML table gradually for a student, so it looks as you want. When you get to a new period, make a new HTML column for it. When you reach a row where the student changes start a new HTML table. That's the basic idea anyway