# How to format join query results in laravel view or controller?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, join

I have five table `students`, `grades`, `subjects`, `terms`, and `scores`. I'm performing an inner join on thes table to return results. This how my schema looks:

Students table:

```
students
--------
id *
name
class_id (fk)
```

Subjects table:

```
subjects
--------
id *
name
```

Class table:

```
classes
--------
id *
name
```

Term table:

```
terms
--------
id *
name
```

Scores Table:

```
scores
---------------
id *
student_id (fk)
subject_id (fk)
class_id (fk)
term_id (fk)
score
```

My laravel query:

```
$scores = \DB::table('scores')
        ->join('students', 'students.id', '=', 'scores.student_id')
        ->join('subjects', 'subjects.id', '=', 'scores.subject_id')
        ->join('grades', 'grades.id', '=', 'scores.grade_id')
        ->join('terms', 'terms.id', '=', 'scores.term_id')
        ->select('students.first_name', 'students.surname', 'subjects.name as subject', 'grades.name as grade', 'terms.name as term', 'score')
        ->where('students.id', 1)
        ->whereBetween('scores.term_id', [1, 3])
        ->get();
```

result return by the query when I die and dump it:

[image]

Without doubt the query is returning the right result, but the **problem** is I want the result to appear in my html table like this:

[image]

This is how it is displaying based on the code I now have in my controller and view.

controller:

```
public function index()
{
    //
    $scores = \DB::table('scores')
        ->join('students', 'students.id', '=', 'scores.student_id')
        ->join('subjects', 'subjects.id', '=', 'scores.subject_id')
        ->join('grades', 'grades.id', '=', 'scores.grade_id')
        ->join('terms', 'terms.id', '=', 'scores.term_id')
        ->select('students.first_name', 'students.surname', 'subjects.name as subject', 'grades.name as grade', 'terms.name as term', 'score')
        ->where('students.id', 1)
        ->whereBetween('scores.term_id', [1, 3])
        ->get();


    // finding details of the student based on id pased
    $student = Student::findOrFail(1);

    // getting the name of the student
    $name = $student->first_name.' '.$student->surname;

    // getting the class or grade of the student (grade 12 or grade 11)
    $grade = $student->grade->name;

    // getting the current date
    $date = Score::date();

    return view('scores.home', compact('scores', 'name', 'date', 'grade'));
```

view:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">Name</th>
            <td colspan="4">{{$name}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">Class</th>
            <td colspan="2">{{$grade}}</td>

            <th scope="row">Date</th>
            <td>{{$date->toFormattedDateString()}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th class="text-center">Subject</th>
            @foreach($scores as $score)
                <th class="text-center">{{$score->term}}</th>
            @endforeach
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach($scores as $score)
            <tr>
                <td>{{$score->subject}}</td>
                <td>{{$score->score}}</td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

result:

[image]

As seen in the result above the term name `1st Period` is being repeated, how do I avoid that? How do I refactor my query or code in view or controller to get the desire results that I want?

Comment: What is your maximum period number ?

Comment: @NazmulHasan That's the catch, I'm actually working on a School Management System for secondary schools in my country. Now, normally there are eight terms six of them are periods and two of them are exams time. Since I'm planning on this being a saas application I can't specify the amount of terms a school may have. For more information on the design please take a look at this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45170192/how-to-rearrange-results-returned-by-inner-join-query

Comment: I understood.But for the solution of your problem, there must be a fixed number of terms. Then I can give you a solution.

Comment: @NazmulHasan let say eight terms 4(1st, 2nd 3rd, 1st exam) for semester one which I'm trying to query now, and four for semester two(4th, 5th, 6th, 2nd exam). Don't forget that I omitted 1st exam and 2nd exam for simplicity sake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First I would simplify the query a bit and only select data you don't already know.
There is no need to return the students name and the grade in every row, since they are always the same.

```
$student = Student::findOrFail(1);

$scores = \DB::table('scores')
    ->join('subjects', 'subjects.id', '=', 'scores.subject_id')
    ->join('terms', 'terms.id', '=', 'scores.term_id')
    ->select('subjects.name as subject', 'terms.name as term', 'score')
    ->where('scores.student_id', $student->id)
    ->whereBetween('scores.term_id', [1, 3])
    ->get();
```

You will get the following collection which is similar to your result:

```
[
    0 => (object)[
        'subject' => 'Mathematics',
        'term' => '1st Period',
        'score' => 99
    ],
    1 => (object)[
        'subject' => 'Biology',
        'term' => '2nd Period',
        'score' => 99
    ],
    2 => (object)[
        'subject' => 'Biology',
        'term' => '3rd Period',
        'score' => 79
    ]
]
```

Now transform it to a nested structure:

```
$scores = $scores->groupBy('subject')->map(function($item){
    return $item->keyBy('term')->map(function($item){
        return $item->score;
    });
});
```

You will get the following collection:

```
    [
        'Mathematics' => [
            '1st Period' => 99,
        ],
        'Biology' => [
            '2nd Period' => 99,
            '3nd Period' => 79
        ]
    ]
```

But this is not a table structure - some terms are missing.
So you somehow need to fill the missing terms, since you don't want to do that in your view.
I would create an empty table structure and fill the data into it:

```
$terms = Term::whereBetween('id', [1, 3])->pluck('name');
// returns: ['1st Period', '2nd Period', '3rd Period']
```

Initialize the table with empty scores:

```
$scoreTable = [];
foreach ($scores->keys() as $subject){
    $scoreTable[$subject] = [];
    foreach ($terms as $term){
        $scoreTable[$subject][$term] = '';
    }
}
```

Fill the table with given scores:

```
foreach ($scores as $subject => $row){
    foreach($row as $term => $score){
        $scoreTable[$subject][$term] = $score;
    }
}
```

Now the "table" will look like this:

```
    [
        'Mathematics' => [
            '1st Period' => 99,
            '2nd Period' => '',
            '3nd Period' => '',
        ],
        'Biology' => [
            '1st Period' => '',
            '2nd Period' => 99,
            '3nd Period' => 79,
        ],
    ]
```

Pass it to your view and render the table like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Subject</th>
        @foreach($terms as $term)
            <th>{{$term}}</th>
        @endforeach
    </tr>
    @foreach($scoreTable as $subject => $scores)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$subject}}</td>
            @foreach($terms as $term)
                <td>{{$scores[$term]}}</td>
            @endforeach
        </tr>
    @endforeach
</table>
```

You will get the following HTML code:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Subject</th>
        <th>1st Period</th>
        <th>2nd Period</th>
        <th>3rd Period</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Mathematics</td>
        <td>99</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Biology</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>99</td>
        <td>79</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

#### Update:

A shorter way to get the `$scoreTable` could be

```
$terms = Term::whereBetween('id', [1, 3])->pluck('name');

$initRow = $terms
    ->keyBy(function($term){ return $term; })
    ->map(function(){ return ''; });

$scoreTable = $scores
    ->groupBy('subject')
    ->map(function($subject) use($initRow){
        $row = $subject
            ->keyBy('term')
            ->map(function($term) use($initRow){
                return $term->score;
            });
        return $initRow->merge($row);
    });
```

But it doesn't seem to be very readable. Also there might be the one or the other `collection` function which would replace the `map` function and make things easier. But I don't know them all.

#### Update 2:

Here's another way which is even shorter, but might be slow on bigger data sets, because the the expensive `where()` function is called twice for each table cell.

```
$scoreTable = [];
foreach ($scores->pluck('subject')->unique() as $subject){
    foreach ($scores->pluck('term')->unique() as $term) {
        $scoreTable[$subject][$term] = $scores
            ->where('subject', $subject)
            ->where('term', $term)
            ->pluck('score')
            ->first();
    }
}
```

#### Update 3:

At the end I came up with the following solution, which (I think) is the most readable/simple and fast.

```
$subjects = $scores->pluck('subject')->unique(); // ['Mathematics', 'Biology']
$terms    = $scores->pluck('term')->unique(); // ['1st Period', '2nd Period', '3rd Period']

$scoreTable = [];
foreach ($subjects as $subject) {
    foreach ($terms as $term) {
        $scoreTable[$subject][$term] = '';
    }
}

foreach ($scores as $row) {
    $scoreTable[$row->subject][$row->term] = $row->score;
}

return view('scores.home', compact('scoreTable', 'terms', 'name', 'date', 'grade'));
```

The first two lines will extract unique subjects and terms from the query result. (More about the [pluck()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-pluck) and the [unique()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-unique) methods you will find in the [laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections).) They are then used in the following nested loop to generate a table structure (subjects ✕ terms) with empty values. In the next loop the scores from the query result are filled in that "table".

Comment: @PaulSpeigel your answer looks promising but there is one thing I fear, maybe I fail to mention. The thing is it is a system many schools are going to use, and not all schools have the same amount of periods. What I'm trying to get is 1st semester report which consists of three periods for most schools. But that may be different for other schools, that's why I'm trying to make it flexible. What I want to add now is another table called `semester` which will be a `one to many relationship` between `semester` and `terms`. A single semester can have multiple periods/terms.

Comment: This is how the new term table may look `term(id, name, semester_id)` **The thing is** after I have done this I don't know how to update my query that if a specific semester id is passed it should query out scores for all the periods/terms that are specific to that student.

Comment: @NathanSiafa I understood your question to be about data restructuring (pivoting), not about data retrieving. Note that the more constraints you add to your question, the less useful it's going to be for other users. However,  the terms are limited by the condition in your question (`whereBetween('scores.term_id', [1, 3])`). If you want to get all terms, just skip that line. If you want to limit them to a specific semester, just add another condition (`where('terms.semester_id', $semester->id)`).

Comment: @PaulSpiegal Thanks for the patience. I'm trying to follow your solution step by step so that I can get a bit understanding of what you're doing. Now, I stage where you title `Now transform it to a nested structure:` and I'm getting this error: `Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in ScoresController.php (line 32)` this is what I have on line 32 `return $item['score'];` when I remove that an empty collection is return by `dd($scores)`

Comment: @NathanSiafa My fault: It should be `$item->score`

Comment: Oh my God I'm sorry I mistakenly give that bounty and now looking for ways on how I can retrieve it and give it to you who rightfully deserve it.

Comment: I feel so bad and ungrateful that this happen. I'm currently seeking ways I can reward you here:https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/353681/retrieve-bounty-that-was-mistakenly-given if you have ideas please let me know.

Comment: @NathanSiafa Don't worry. Shit happens :-)

Comment: I'm thankful and at the same time feel sorry for what happen.  Your solution works well but there parts I would love to understand a little bit. First the part where you **transform the scores return to a nested structure** second the part where you **initialize the table with empty scores** and lastly the part where you **fill the table with given scores**. Are there resources you can point me to in order to grab the concept of what you're doing? Thanks so much for the effort, appreciate it a whole lot.

Comment: @NathanSiafa Please have a look at the last update. I hope it's easier to understand.

Comment: Thanks very much. I now understand a bit of how things are working.

Comment: can we talk via social media or email. I want to discuss something important with you.

Comment: what I want use to talk about isn't about this thread I promise. Can we please talk.

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel we have Laravel eloquent, you just need to define the relationships and you are good to go.
In your scores model, assuming you have one, just define the relationships

```
public function student(){
   return $this->belongsTo(student::class, 'student_id', 'id');
}
```

In the controller, or the routes, depending on where you working from, just call the scores

```
$scores = Score::all();
return view('scores.home', compact('scores'));
```

When you calling the student in blade you just write `{{$score->student->name}}`

Then do the same for all other items, i.e. grades, terms etc.

Comment: If you haven't notice I'm planning on this being a function to display a specific student report. So, I really don't understand how your solution fits in. Can you be a bit explicit?

Comment: What I'm saying is, whatever you trying to do can be easily achieved using **Laravel's Eloquent model**, especially when you using the relationships in laravel, `one to one`,  `one to many`, and `many to many`, in your case, many scores belong to one student, many scores belong to one term and many scores belongs to one subject ... you get what I mean.

Comment: I understand now. But how do I arrange a student score specific to a period. Like all subjects score for a student in first period is placed directly under the first period column and so forth for the rest.

Answer (score 0):

I would collect the scores paired with his subject by doing something like this:

```
$scores_paired = collect();

foreach($student->subjects as $subject){
   $scores_paired->push($scores->where('subject', $subject->name)->sortBy('term','ASC'));
}
```

Then pass this new collection to the view so you will be able to loop the `$scores_paired` in your view

Comment: where do you get $student->subjects from?

Comment: I thought that you have some method to retrieve student's subjects if not just replace it with `Subjects::all()`

Comment: based on what you suggested please take a look at this gist(https://gist.github.com/anonymous/776a79e71534f5856997c695d88aa766) I created. What you suggested is still returning the right results, but I have no Idea on how to format it in my view.